# How to label Table Header Label Date vs. Date/Time

Tags: tables, labels, dates, column-headers

I have a table with a date time column.  Right now the label reads "Closure Date" and it seems fine to me.

I was wondering it was better practice to label it something like "Closure Date/Time".

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf7gr/) for the example. *Screen shot:*

[image: header label options]

Option 1 is the current usage.  Two is the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual for 'dates' to include times or for 'times' to include dates, so I don't think many people would be confused by the shorter heading. That said, it's good to be explicit if you have space for the longer heading.

Perhaps more important is making the purpose of that date/time clear. Consider whether your users will know what "closure" means.

Comment: They will definitely know what closure means.  There will be some more context on the page to identify this, but I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Users will see that the column contains dates and times, so I'd argue that you don't need to tell them what they're looking at. "Closure" is the only important word in there so I'd recommend just using that as the column header.